# ggplot facet_wrap with classic theme: how to fix the bolded boxes around some (but not all) labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make grouped barplots on `ggplot` using `facet_wrap` and `theme_classic`. It all comes out as expected but when I export it as an EPS file, some of the boxes around the labels become bold for some reason. I've tried to fix this by setting `theme(strip.background = element_rect(linewidth = xxx)` but it still persists. Is this a bug or am I missing something? And if it's a bug, is there a way to work around it?

Here's an example using the iris dataset:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- iris %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Species)

ggplot(data, aes(x = name, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ Species, nrow = 2) +
  theme_classic()
)
```

On the viewer in RStudio, the graph looks like this:

[image]

But when I export it as EPS, it looks like this (sertosa and virginica have thicker boxes):

[image]

Comment: How are you exporting it as an EPS file? From the preview window, or using ggsave, or something else?

Comment: @JonSpring I'm using the preview window in RStudio (so Plot -> Export -> Save as Image)

Comment: Maybe try `ggplot2::ggsave(filename = "great_plot.eps", plot = last_plot(), device = cairo_ps)` You can also specify the exact dimensions you want to make it repeatable.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work! (although the`cairo_ps` for the device did not work, so I did it with `"eps"`)